# Applescript: read text from file

Tags: file, applescript

I can't read text from text file using applescript. Tried this:

```
set sharesFileName to (the POSIX path of (path to home folder)) & "Applications/mounts"
set sharesLines to paragraphs of (read POSIX file sharesFileName as "class utf8" using delimiter linefeed)
```

Got "Script Error", "End of file error"

What am I doing wrong? File, surely, exists and readable

Comment: Delete `POSIX file`. `read` accepts POSIX paths.

Comment: Tried and didn't help...

https://tut.etogo.net/in/applescripterror2.jpg

Comment: EOF error means the file is empty.

Comment: Looks like the "end of file" is related to the script, not to the file   $ ls -l ~/Applications/mounts -rw-r--r--  1 viktor  staff  153 Feb 24 20:22 /Users/viktor/Applications/mounts

Comment: Try doing `cat /Users/viktor/Applications/mounts`

Comment: cat shows it’s content ok

Comment: It's difficult to know where the error is without knowing the format of the "mounts" file and what the exact error message you are getting and on what particular line.

Comment: It’s lust a text file, contains lines “one”, “two” and “three” separated by \n

Comment: Try creating a new script with just these two lines `set sharesFileName to (the POSIX path of "/Users/viktor/Applications/mounts")` and `set sharesLines to read sharesFileName`. What is the result?

Comment: https://etogo.net/in/applescripterror2.jpg

Comment: Try adding this at the top of the script `use AppleScript version "2.4"` followed by `use scripting additions`...

Comment: Can you zip the file and upload it so we can look at the file?

Comment: "Syntax error" "A “"” can’t go after this property."
https://tut.etogo.net/in/applescript/mount.tgz

Comment: I quit scripteditor and recreated the file. Now it works but reads the file char by char. Maybe I need to set the delimiter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `mounts` is a plain text file, then the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* should work:

```
set sharesFileName to (the POSIX path of (path to home folder)) & "Applications/mounts"
set sharesLines to read sharesFileName
```

Example:

```
$ cat mounts
one
two
three
$
```

Using:

```
set sharesLines to read sharesFileName
```

Results:

```
"one
two
three
"
```

Using:

```
set sharesLines to read sharesFileName using delimiter linefeed
```

Results:

```
{"one", "two", "three"}
```

Using:

```
set sharesLines to paragraphs of (read sharesFileName)
```

Results:

```
{"one", "two", "three", ""}
```

As you can see the last example includes the last `linefeed` as an empty string in the file, where using `using delimiter linefeed` does not, and both create a `list`. So if you want `sharesLines` to be as `list`, then use:

```
set sharesLines to read sharesFileName using delimiter linefeed
```

If you want `sharesLines` to just contain the contents of `mounts` as *paragraphs of text*, then use:

```
set sharesLines to read sharesFileName
```

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not employ any *error handling* and is meant only to show one of many ways accomplish a task. The onus is always upon the User to add/use appropriate *error handling* as needed/wanted.

Comment: @BbIKTOP, I just tested my code with the 'mounts' file in https://tut.etogo.net/in/applescript/mount.tgz and it works without issue!

Comment: It's very strange. What could it be? Now it works on my mac as well! I just quit and reopen the script editor!

Comment: But the most strange thing is that my original code now works as well!

Comment: @BbIKTOP, I've added some more content to may answer, so you might want to have a second look.

Comment: Yes, it's understood, thank you! I just wonder why it was not working. Ok, maybe it's a kind of apple magic )

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using the latest version of Sierra(After reading your comment it was only a simple text file)

```
set sharesFileName to (the POSIX path of (path to home folder)) & "Applications/mounts.txt"
set sharesLines to paragraphs of (read sharesFileName)
```